# Can I use the return value from Mockito thenReturn() as an argument on the next Mockito when()?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

Can I do something like this:

```
final var msg = Mockito.when(mapper.map(request)).thenReturn(message);        
final var resp = Mockito.when(messaging.send(msg.getMock())).thenReturn(response);
```

Instead of msg inside messaging.send() I have Mockito.any(), if I try with msg I am getting a ClassCastException.

Is something like that possible in any way?

Comment: Why would you do this? You return what you need in your code/mock so you can verify the code you want. Using a mock value to get another mock value makes no sense to me. Or provide the code you want to test so we can have a peak :)

Comment: @svrdoljak I want to verify that messaging.send() method is called with the argument provided by the mapper.map()

Comment: You can use an ArgumentCaptor instead. If you want to verify that a method is using an exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example code. Maybe not the exact syntax because I'm on my mobile phone:

`ArgumentCaptor captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class); //or any other class your argument is`

`Mockito.verify(service.yourMethod(captor.capture());`

`Assertions.assertThat(captor.getValue()).isEqualTo(yourExpectedValue):`